# How to solve nonlinear simultaneous equations for geometric progression?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a program that will help with geometric progressions. I can find the sum, the term, the term value as long as the user provides the first and second term. I want to code something that will solve a nonlinear simultaneous equation and find the value for the first term, a and the common ratio, r by itself.

I have used the formula ar^n-1 = [term value] for my coding

Like, for example, if I input the 3rd term to be 45 and the fifth term to be 405, I want the program to output, 5 as a and 3 as r.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

any_num1 = int(input("Enter the term "))
any_num1_value = int(input("Enter its value: "))

any_num2 = int(input("Enter the term "))
any_num2_value = int(input("Enter its value: "))

def equations(p):
    a, r = p
    return (a*r**any_num1-1-any_num1_value, a*r**any_num2-1-any_num2_value)

a, r =  fsolve(equations, (1, 1))

print(equations((a, r)))
```

Comment: Your problem is `5*3**3-1-45` does not evaluate to `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution is all about math.

```
any_num1 = int(input("Enter the term "))
any_num1_value = int(input("Enter its value: "))

any_num2 = int(input("Enter the term "))
any_num2_value = int(input("Enter its value: "))

term_difference = any_num1 - any_num2 if any_num1 > any_num2 else any_num2 - any_num1
b,c = (any_num1_value, any_num2_value) if any_num1_value > any_num2_value else 
(any_num2_value, any_num1_value) 


r = int((b / c) ** (1/term_difference))
a = int(any_num1_value / (r ** (any_num1 - 1)))

print("First term:" + str(a))
print("Ratio:" + str(r))
```